# Better way to present/query the months table

Tags: mysql

I need some new oder better ideas to solve this problem:

I have two tables.

1. Table: Users with userid, firstname and lastname
2. Table: Paid Membership Fee id, userid, amount, month and year

Now i have to present in a table the users and the months, in which montly fees are paid with a tick.

This is the solution now...:

```
function getUserWithInvoices ()
{ 
    global $pdo;
    $userlist_with_invoices_query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT mv.*,GROUP_CONCAT(month, '') as month, GROUP_CONCAT(amount, '') as amount, GROUP_CONCAT(status, '') as status, GROUP_CONCAT(year, '') as year FROM users mv INNER JOIN invoices inv ON mv.id=inv.user_id GROUP BY inv.user_id");
    $userlist_with_invoices = array();

    if ($userlist_with_invoices_query->execute())  
    {
        while ($row6 = $userlist_with_invoices_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {

            $userlist_with_invoice=new UserlistWithInvoice($row6['id'],$row6['vorname'],$row6['nachname'],$row6['month'],$row6['status'],$row6['year']);
            array_push($userlist_with_invoices , $userlist_with_invoice);

        }

                    
        
        
        
    }
    
        return $userlist_with_invoices;
}
```

and the PHP HTML Part:

```
<table id="memberfee_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Vorname</th>
            <th>Nachname</th>

            <th>Jan.</th>
            <th>Feb.</th>
            <th>Mar.</th>
            <th>Apr.</th>
            <th>Mai</th>
            <th>Jun.</th>
            <th>Jul.</th>
            <th>Aug.</th>
            <th>Sep.</th>
            <th>Okt.</th>
            <th>Nov.</th>
            <th>Dez.</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php foreach ($userlist_with_invoices as $userelement)
    {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'. $userelement->surname .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->lastname .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month1 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month2 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month3 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month4 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month5 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month6 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month7 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month8 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month9 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month10 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month11 .'</td>
            <td>'. $userelement->month12 .'</td>


        </tr>
';
}
?>



            </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the result I like very much, but the problem is that the only users displayed in the list are those who also have an entry in the "Paid Mambership fee" table.
[image: Screenshot of thable]

I would like all users to be displayed, not just those who have paid for at least one month....

I'm also open for complete new approaches :D Thanks

Comment: So you need a query that gets all your users... just use your imagination.

Comment: outer join, right outer join doesnt work...

Comment: There's no table `Paid Membership Fee` in your query. Also you might want to try using `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: The Paid Membership Fee table is the invoices table

Comment: Post a sample data in textual form. If you can, create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0). Also, please state your MySQL version, you can check by running `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 0):

Create a third table of months with a month no. to order by.

Join users and months and a left outer join on invoices. Order by user id and month no.

You will then have a row returned per user per month in a convenient order to fill your table.

If you group by user id, and do the same group concat, you can keep the same logic in your php, although I'm sure that a tidier solution exists.

Comment: SELECT * from igmg_users mv JOIN months LEFT OUTER JOIN invoices inv ON months.month_no=inv.month;

This is not working... how i have to design the SQL?

Comment: I new used following Query. It outputs now for every user 12 rows (12 months) and the months where the user has no data in invoices table (membership fee) there the status is "null".

How can i now output it on one line if every user has 12 rows...?